# Using rTorrent UI while running as daemon

Tags: server, ssh, services, rtorrent

I have rTorrent running as a daemon on my headless server, but I can't access the UI in any obvious way per the config or instructions online. I'd like to be able to pass in magnet links and manage the current torrent files using the UI, but be able to let it run seeding/downloading torrents outside of my ssh session. Unless I'm missing something obvious, I see three options for how to address this problem:

1). Stop the service and run rTorrent as the active application, then restart the service when I'm finished interacting with it. This would work as .session saves the current state between uses but it would be annoying due to how long it takes to notify trackers and close.
2). Run another application to attach to the daemon process somehow.
3). Understand that daemon mode is only intended for passive use like watch directory functionality or simple seeding, and that my desired use case is impossible.

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [flood](https://github.com/jesec/flood) as web ui for rTorrent on my NAS. It allows to add magnet links, suspend/resume downloads and pretty convenient UI.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll check that out. Thanks, I appreciate the tip.